# poisson distribution of chocolate

Tags: statistics

Let the number of chocolate drops in a certain type of cookie have a Poisson
distribution. We want the probability that a cookie of this type contains at least
two chocolate drops to be greater than 0.99. Find the smallest value of the mean
that the distribution can take.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the number $D$ of drops has a distribution $D \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
  P(D \ge 2) &= 1 - P(D < 2)\\
             &= 1 - P(D = 0) - P(D = 1)\\
             &= 1 - \exp(-\lambda)\cdot (1 + \lambda)
\end{align*}
So $P(D \ge 2) \ge 0.99$ iff $\exp(-\lambda)(1 + \lambda) \le \frac 1{100}$. As $\lambda \mapsto \exp(-\lambda)(1+ \lambda)$ has a negative derivative on $(0,\infty)$, it is strictly decreasing. So there is a unique $\lambda_0$ with $\exp(-\lambda_0)(1+\lambda_0) = \frac 1{100}$ (there is no closed form for $\lambda_0$ in terms of elementary functions, [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-l%29%2a%281%2bl%29%20=%201/100) tells us it is approximately 6.6384). This is the minimal mean you looked for.

Comment: Can you help me with this problem: Let X1 ,X2 , . . . ,Xk-1 have a multinomial distribution. Find the mgf of X2,X3,...,Xk-1.

Comment: @user48495 
"We know that the MGF of a multinomial distribution is:

$M(t_1, t_2,...t_k-1) = (p_1*e^t_1 + .... + p_k+1*e^t_k+1 + p_k)^n$

hence, the MGF of $X_2$, $X_3$, .... $X_k-1$ is

$M(0, t_2,...t_k-1) = (p_1 + .... + p_k+1*e^t_k+1 + p_k)^n$"
-adapted from rad at http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/archive/index.php/t-121247.html